# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in command prompt

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I run from command line program created by Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276219/can-i-run-from-command-line-program-created-by-eclipse)

I am getting below exception when I try to run class file from command prompt,the same I run in eclipse,there I don't get any error

Trying to run from the same folder

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testClient (wrong nam
    e: com/mindcraft/queryExecutor/actionclass/testClient)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    Could not find the main class: testClient.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Does the folder contain a file called testClient.class?

Comment: Make sure you have all the classes and the libraries you need in the classpath. In eclipse, you have this information on the Build Path.

Comment: What does this have to do with RMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before posting a question kindly Search enough if the question has been asked before or even better answered before. When i Googled i found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276219/883811) being answered. Hope the link provides you the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're running *in* a directory of `com/mindcraft/queryExecutor/actionclass`

Instead, you should be running in the root directory (i.e. the parent of `com`), like this:

```
java com.mindcraft.queryExecutor.actionclass.testClient
```

Comment: tried the same ,still getting the same error.

Comment: @happy: I very much doubt that you're getting the *same* error, if you ran exactly what I said. Of course, you've hardly given us any information, which makes it hard to go on... you haven't told us how you're building, what you're trying to run etc.

Answer (score 2):

run the .class file from root directory with full name space. i.e, if your class is in com.test package as com.test.App.java in your src then on compiling its class file will have a qualified class name as full name. i.e, com.test.App.class

So from your root/src run it as  java com.test.App in command line.